# Is is ok to modify incoming data in rest API?

Tags: rest, http

Say we have an rest-api regarding customers with one GET-endpoint and one POST-endpoint
When using POST to create a customer I send in firstname: "Firstname". (Case-sensitive)
Beforing saving the data it is modified to uppercase so the value becomes "FIRSTNAME".

When using GET to retrive a customer with value "Firstname" will return 0 customers but using "FIRSTNAME" will return the above created customer.

Is this behaviour accepted following standards like http or rest?

Comment: If this is the business requirement, yes, but looks weird. But for me when you search for a string, the comparison should be case insensitive.

Comment: I agree with this. But if the api in question should be one where I'm not the owner and there is for example some kind of partnership between two companies? I guess that it then comes down to what these companies have decided together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this behaviour accepted following standards like http or rest?

Yes.

> The POST method requests that the target resource process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics -- [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-9.3.3).

"UPPERCASE ALL THE THINGS" is permitted because pretty much anything is permitted for POST.  See also: [it is okay to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).

Neither REST nor HTTP require that your resource design be *good*; they only require that your resource design uses the same message semantics as every other resource on the web.